# is "Bee" a moniker?

Tags: nicknames

Sometimes the word "Bee" is used affectionately to describe a woman you care about. 
Examples: "Hi Bee". "I love you Bee".
People also use the word "Boo" in a similar way.
Would this be a moniker?
I feel like there must be a better word to use to classify it?

Comment: I'd call that a "pet name" rather than a "moniker", unless "Bee" is the name by which one is known more generally.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking of *bae*?

Comment: @MikeGraham no i wasnt thinking of "bae". Tho it does seem to often be used in the same context. Isnt it an acronym for "before anyone else," or a shortened version of baby or babe?
But perhaps it could fall under the same classification of word.

Comment: @nnnnnn "pet name" seems to slang its self. Im looking for a more formal classification.

Comment: "Pet name" isn't slang, it's a pretty standard term which in my opinion is perfectly acceptable in formal English. "Term of endearment" is another common option. Regarding "bae" (which *is* slang), it's not an acronym, it's a bacronym.

Comment: If *Bee* is in widespread use as a pet name, I would have expected such a definition to be high at https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bee

Comment: I think Bee is just an abbreviation of Beatrice. Boo *could* be short for Boudicca - after the Queen of the Celtic Iceni tribe - but as she was pronounced Bo-de-seer until quite recently the traditional abbreviation would have been Bo.

Comment: Yes, Bee (or Bea) is short for Beatrice in my experience. We once had a fearsome female prison inmate of that name on an Australian TV series and she is my prototype for that name (but I’m sure you are much nicer than her, Bee): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner_(TV_series)

Comment: Whether Bee is being used as the shortened form of Beatrix or not, I’d call the name a “nickname” (a familiar name or shortened name). To me “pet name” has “cutsie” overtones, like an adoring husband calling his wife “Sweetie-pie”.